# Create Array without nullable types from Array with nullable types

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In Kotlin we have to distinguish between nullable types and not nullable types. Let's say I have an `Array<String?>` fom which I know that every value within it is actually not null. Is there an easy way to create an `Array<String>` from the source array without copying it?

Comment: How about `mapNotNull().toArray()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array.requireNoNulls()` returns same array `Array<T?>` with non-optional type `Array<T>` (But throws `IllegalArgmentException` if any of the item found `null`).

if you are sure that your array doesn't have `null` then you can typecast.

`array as Array<String>`

Comment: *array.requireNoNulls() is safer to use* in what sense? It throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if there are any `null` elements.

Comment: @forpas Good catch. I have updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Array.[filterNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) might be the safer way to do it. But it will create a new Array.

```
val items: Array<String?> = arrayOf("one", "two", null, "three")
val itemsWithoutNull: List<String> = items.filterNotNull()
```

Comment: question says without copying it. `filterNotNull` creates new `ArrayList` and adds `Non-Null` values to that before returning it.